# Military uniform identification ?French

Tags: identification, france, uniform

This photo comes from a collection from my great grandmother. When she was in her 20's she is supposed to have been nanny to this officer's children. Supposedly his name was Jean Lerede and he was French. I'm not sure if this photo is him or if the soldier is even French. Can anyone identify him?
Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Your great grandmother isn't very helpful without knowing what years she was in her 20s.

Comment: The regiment numbers on the collar look very French. Also the medal on the right (as you look at him) looks like the Croix de Guerre. I'm not sure that adds much information to what you already have though

Comment: ... and the medal on the left looks like the Médaille Militaire (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9daille_militaire), so it seems pretty conclusive that this is a picture of a French soldier. Seems like both medals were quite widely awarded, especially during WWI, so I don't think this is much help in tracking him down.

Comment: she was born in 1874 and looked after the kids in the late 1890's before she got married in 1902. She kept up the friendship with the French family for many years after.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably a French army uniform of WWI (or soon after), for a couple of reasons.

Firstly, the number patches on the collar are distinctive of French army uniforms around this period. The number indicates what regiment the wearer belongs to; in this case, it's '30'. French Wikipedia suggests several potential regiments that this could be:

- [30e régiment de dragons](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/30e_r%C3%A9giment_de_dragons)
- [30e régiment d'infanterie](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/30e_r%C3%A9giment_d%27infanterie_(France))
- [30e régiment d'infanterie territoriale](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/30e_r%C3%A9giment_d%27infanterie_territoriale)

Secondly, the two medals also look like French decorations. From left to right (as we look at them):

- The [Médaille militaire](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9daille_militaire).
- The [Croix de Guerre](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croix_de_Guerre). This was first awarded in 1915, so it dates the photo to WWI or later. The pattern of the ribbon indicates what war it was awarded for; unfortunately the photo resolution isn't high enough to make out a pattern.

Both these medals were awarded to members of allied armies (and civillians). However, given the collar patches, I'm pretty confident that this is a French uniform.

The OP says of their great grandmother:

> she was born in 1874 and looked after the kids in the late 1890's before she got married in 1902. She kept up the friendship with the French family for many years after.

Given that this photo was taken after 1915, it could either be her former employer, or one of the children she looked after. Or it could be someone else entirely!

Comment: thanks so much Jayfor. I appreciate your help

Comment: Regarding the CdG medal it also has palm and star additions on the ribbon though what grade is uncertain due to the colour of the photo.

Comment: @foolingreens - you're welcome. I'm afraid none of this information is of much use in identifying the person in the photo, but I guess it at least gives you an earliest date. If you're really invested in finding out more,  there is an old question on Genealogy stack exchange about French army records which might be useful https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/seeking-army-records-for-jean-baptiste-cordier-an-officer-in-the-french-army